# Можно ли обособить оборот?

Tags: запятые

> Мне было странно, особенно когда мне(,) от Георга-мастера(,) пришло письмище трёхтонное.

Comment: Как вы узнаете, нужно ли подчеркивать оборот или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Можно**, если автор хочет подчеркнуть значимость оборота для смыслового выделения или для пояснения:

*Мне было странно, особенно когда мне, от Георга-мастера, пришло письмище трёхтонное*.

Если автор не подчëркивает оборот, соответственно, он его не обособит:

*Мне было странно, особенно когда мне от Георга-мастера пришло письмище трёхтонное*.

Опять-таки, пунктуацию выбирает именно **автор**. Та же [ссылка](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114).

Answer (score 2):

Возможны **варианты по СИТУАЦИИ:**

(1) *Мне было странно, особенно когда мне, **от Георга-мастера**, пришло письмище трёхтонное.*

Мне обычно не присылают такие письма. Здесь "от Георга-мастера" является **дополнительной** информацией.

(2) *Мне было странно, особенно когда мне **от Георга-мастера** пришло письмище трёхтонное.*

Мне Георг-мастер обычно ничего не пишет, а тут вдруг приходит трехтонное письмище. Здесь "от Георга-мастера" является **основной** информацией.